# Problem - Ubuntu 12.10 + JDK + Netbeans

Tags: jdk, netbeans

Hey guys I downloaded the latest version of netbeans from their site. Also downloaded latest JDK from Oracle.

Installed both of them but whenever I am opening netbeans and trying to create a new project its giving me this jdk error

http://s13.postimage.org/5ahdmdq3b/Screenshot_from_2013_01_14_22_03_43.png

System not allowing me to post images so here is the link.

while jdk has already been installed. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

You might want to remove what you installed because that might conflict whith what eclipse want's to pull down.

---

Why on earth would you want to run netbeans on a linux. Netbeans is primarily designed for windows, and while they "support" linux (according to them) that stuff dosen't really works.

My recommendation to you is to use eclipse instead. In a terminal run:

```
apt-get install eclipse
```

And this will download everything needed for java development. (Also on a personal note: Eclipse's workspace management makes more sense than netbeans'.)